# Is there a command line utility that can copy Apple TV metadata and embed it into MP4 video files?

Tags: itunes, video, appletv, metadata

Is there a way (preferably an open-source command line tool) to copy Apple TV (the desktop application that replaced part of iTunes in Catalina) metadata into the MP4 files so that when transferred to a different machine/OS (or the files are re-added after a deletion) the data is not lost and the Apple TV application can still pick it up?

Comment: This is two distinct questions - one about Apple TV and the meta data it recognizes and a software rec.  Both are good, but needs to be separated and the software recommendation question needs to be more focused.  See:  [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation) for help building your query.

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: Have a look at https://exiftool.org/

Comment: I use mp4tags for setting the metadata tags in MP4 videos.  If you do it on videos you own and load into iTunes, you can play it on iTunes or Home Sharing on an ATV.  I don't have the new macOS-based TV app, so I can't comment on how to load videos into that, but if it behaves like my (old) iTunes, it should take your home/personal MP4's.